# Eclipse - can't write < and > symbols

Tags: eclipse, osx-mavericks

I'm using Eclipse Kepler on OSX mavericks and I cannot type < or > characters in the editor (I can anywhere else). I removed the key bindings from the `shift+alt+x` and `shift+alt+y` but now the editor says in the lower right corner: "No matches"

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These keybinding issues only get fixed if you restart your Eclipse instance after removing or altering the keybindings. Hurts me very often.

Comment: Oh god thank you! The restart solved it :D (only if i restart eclipse immediately after the key binding change)